# Is reversing the order of integration possible here. If so where do I make a mistake?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I've been looking to solve this problem for a few hours now. But I don't seem to progress to the give solution at all. Maybe you could be of some help to me. The question is as follows:

"Reverse the order of integration and evaluate the resulting iterated integral"

$$\int_{-2}^{4}\int_{\frac{x_2^2}{2}-3}^{x_2+1}(x_1)dx_1dx_2$$

```
So what I did is this:
```

$$x_{1}=x_{2}+1 \Rightarrow x_2=x_1-1$$
$$x_1=\frac{(x^2)}{2}-3 \Rightarrow x_2= -\sqrt{2x_1+6}$$
Given that where
$$x_2=4 \Rightarrow x_1 = 4+1 = 5 $$
Then for,
$$x_2=-2 \Rightarrow x_1=\frac{-2^2}{2}-3=-1$$

Which if I'm right gives me the new intervals for the reverse iterated interval. Namely,

$$\int_{-1}^{5}\left(\int_{-\sqrt{2x_1+6}}^{x_1-1}(x_1)dx_2\right)dx_1$$

Then integrated to:
$$\int_{-1}^{5}\left[x_1*(x_1-1)-(x_1*-\sqrt{2x_1+6})\right] dx_1 $$

According to my teachers solution manual the solution should be should be (18/5). Which is the solution to the integral when not reversing the order of integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good work!

You must have:
$$x_1=x_2+1 \Rightarrow x_2=x_1-1\\
x_1=\frac{x_2^2}{2}-3 \Rightarrow x_2=\color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{2x_1+6}$$
There will be two integrals:
$$\begin{align}\int_{-2}^{4}\int_{\frac{x_2^2}{2}-3}^{x_2+1}(x_1)dx_1dx_2&=\int_{-3}^{-1} \int_{-\sqrt{2x_1+6}}^{\sqrt{2x_1+6}} x_1 \, dx_2\, dx_1+\int_{-1}^{5} \int_{x_1-1}^{\sqrt{2x_1+6}} x_1 \, dx_2\, dx_1=\\
&=\int_{-3}^{-1}2x_1\sqrt{2x_1+6} \,dx_1+\int_{-1}^{5}x_1(\sqrt{2x_1+6}-x_1+1) \,dx_1=\\
&=A+B=\\
&-\frac{48}{5}+\frac{66}{5}=\\
&=\frac{18}{5},\\
A&=\int_{-3}^{-1}(2x_1+6-6)\sqrt{2x_1+6} \,dx_1=\\
&=\int_{-3}^{-1}(2x_1+6)^{3/2} \,dx_1-6\int_{-3}^{-1}(2x_1+6)^{1/2} \,dx_1=\\
&=\frac{(2x_1+6)^{5/2}}{2(5/2)}|_{-3}^{-1}-\frac{6(2x_1+6)^{3/2}}{2(3/2)}|_{-3}^{-1}=\\
&=\left(\frac{32}{5}-0\right)-(16-0)=\\
&=-\frac{48}{5}\\
B&=\frac12\int_{-1}^{5}(2x_1+6-6)(\sqrt{2x_1+6}-x_1+1) \,dx_1=\\
&=\frac12\int_{-1}^{5}(2x_1+6)^{3/2} \,dx_1-3\int_{-1}^{5}(2x_1+6)^{1/2} \,dx_1+\int_{-1}^5 -x_1^2+x_1 \,dx_1=\\
&=\frac{(2x_1+6)^{5/2}}{4(5/2)}|_{-1}^5-\frac{3(2x_1+6)^{3/2}}{2(3/2)}|_{-1}^5+\left(-\frac13x_1^3+\frac12x_1^2\right)|_{-1}^5=\\
&=\left(\frac{4^5}{10}-\frac{2^5}{10}\right)-(4^3-2^3)+(-30)=\\
&=\frac{66}{5}.\end{align}$$
See the graph:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

Note: Calculating the original integral is a lot less tedious.

Comment: The really important thing in this answer is it correctly takes the minimum value of $x_1$ as $-3,$ not $-1,$ so it includes the part of the region colored yellow in the figure. That part gets left out when you only integrate over $-1 < x_1 < 5.$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, as David K noted you should consider not only the border points ($x_2=-2, x_2=4$), but also the critical (turning) points if any ($x_2=0$). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowinf for the fact that $x_2$ may be negative.  I think you should break the outer integral up into two cases: $$\begin{align}-2&\leq x_2\leq0\\0&\leq x_2\leq5\end{align} $$

Then consider the sign when you take square roots.

Comment: Hi Saul, thank you for replying so quickly! I don't think $$x_2$$ can be larger than 4. Do you get 18/5 as a solution when you try to solve it?